# Creating a ModelBinder for MongoDB ObjectId on Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I'm trying to create a very simple model binder for ObjectId types in my models but can't seem to make it work so far.

Here's the model binder:

```
public class ObjectIdModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var result = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.FieldName);
        return Task.FromResult(new ObjectId(result.FirstValue));
    }
}
```

This is the ModelBinderProvider I've coded:

```
public class ObjectIdModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(ObjectId))
        {
            return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(ObjectIdModelBinder));
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Here's the class I'm trying to bind the body parameter to:

```
public class Player
{
    [BsonId]
    [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(ObjectIdModelBinder))]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public Guid PlatformId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
}
```

This is the action method:

```
[HttpPost("join")]
public async Task<SomeThing> Join(Player player)
{
    return await _someService.DoSomethingOnthePlayer(player);
}
```

For this code to work, I mean for the model binder to run, I inherited the controller from Controller and removed the `[FromBody]` attribute from the Player parameter.

When I run this, I can step into BindModelAsync method of the model binder, however I can't seem to get the Id parameter value from the post data. I can see the *bindingContext.FieldName* is correct; it is set to *Id* but *result.FirstValue* is null.

I've been away from Asp.Net MVC for a while, and it seems lots of things have been changed and became more confusing :-)

**EDIT**
Based on comments I think I should provide more context.

If I put [FromBody] before the Player action parameter, *player* is set to null. If I remove [FromBody], *player* is set to a default value, not to the values I post. The post body is shown below, it's just a simple JSON:

```
{
    "Id": "507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"
    "PlatformId": "9c8aae0f-6aad-45df-a5cf-4ca8f729b70f"
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that `var result = ..` is `null`?

Comment: No, not the result. But result.FirstValue is null. Also edited the question.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `Request.Form` (or `Request.Body`) does actually contain a value for `id`?

Comment: What do you pass as input? Can you post your test input as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I remove [FromBody], *player* is set to a default value, not to the values I post.

Reading data from the body is *opt-in* (unless you're using [`[ApiController]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#annotation-with-apicontrollerattribute)). When you remove `[FromBody]` from your `Player` parameter, the model-binding process will look to populate properties of `Player` using the route, query-string and form-values, by default. In your example, there are no such properties in these locations and so none of `Player`'s properties get set.

> If I put [FromBody] before the Player action parameter, *player* is set to null.

With the presence of the `[FromBody]` attribute, the model-binding process attempts to read from the body according to the `Content-Type` provided with the request. If this is `application/json`, the body will be parsed as JSON and mapped to your `Player`'s properties. In your example, the JSON-parsing process fails as it doesn't know how to convert from a `string` to an `ObjectId`. When this happens, `ModelState.IsValid` within your controller will return `false` and your `Player` parameter will be `null`.

> For this code to work, I mean for the model binder to run, I inherited the controller from Controller and removed the [FromBody] attribute from the Player parameter.

When you remove `[FromBody]`, the `[ModelBinder(...)]` attribute you've set on your `Id` property is respected and so your code runs. However, with the presence of `[FromBody`], this attribute effectively is ignored. There's a lot going on behind-the-scenes here, but essentially it boils down to the fact that you've already opted-in to model-binding from the body as JSON and that's where model-binding stops in this scenario.

---

I mentioned above that it's the JSON-parsing process that's failing here due to not understanding how to process `ObjectId`. As this JSON-parsing is handled by Newtonsoft.Json (aka JSON.NET), a possible solution is to create a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm). This is covered well here on Stack Overflow, so I won't go into the details of *how* it works. Here's a complete example (error-handling omitted for brevity and laziness):

```
public class ObjectIdJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) =>
        objectType == typeof(ObjectId);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        ObjectId.Parse(reader.Value as string);

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        writer.WriteValue(((ObjectId)value).ToString());
}
```

To make use of this, just replace your existing `[ModelBinder(...)]` attribute with a `[JsonConverter(...)]` attribute, like this:

```
[BsonId]
[JsonConverter(typeof(ObjectIdJsonConverter))]    
public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
```

Alternatively, you can register `ObjectIdJsonConverter` globally so that it applies to all `ObjectId` properties, using something like this in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new ObjectIdJsonConverter());
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You were mistaken at ModelBinder. Correct code:

```
public class ObjectIdModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var result = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.FieldName);

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(new ObjectId(result.FirstValue));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```