# How do I provide a custom model binder for a property on a model from body?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding, asp.net-core-webapi, json-deserialization

I am having issues writing a custom model binder for an ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web API service. I have an action method like the follow

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveAccountEvents([FromRoute] Guid accountId, IList<AccountEvent> events)
{
}
```

The AccountEvent class has a bunch of properties including

```
[BindProperty(BinderType = typeof(CustomBinding))]
public string EventBody { get; set; }
```

The intent is that I want the value of this property coming from the client to be either a string or a JObject (JSON). The idea is that the client can either send stringified JSON or JSON in EventBody, and the model will store it as a string - ending up as stringified JSON.

The problem that I'm running into is that within my custom binding, `bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue` never returns anything. Looking at the property, it contains only a `RouteValueProvider`. I don't see any way that I can get values out of the body. Is there some other way of customizing JSON deserialization in an ASP.NET Core Web API?

**Update:**

This API is used by clients to send event data. The event data consists of a envelope that contains things like event name, date sent, user who initiated the event, etc. In the current version the actual event data is sent as stringified JSON. So right now, a request would look like (notice event body is a string):

```
{
  "eventDate": "20180909",
  "eventBody": "{
      \"newLastName\": \"bob\",
      \"primaryApplication\": \"bob\"
    }"
}
```

The change is that I want to be able to accept the event body as JSON. In this case, the client should be able to send (note that the event body is proper JSON):

```
{
  "eventDate": "20180909",
  "eventBody": {
    "newLastName": "bob",
    "primaryApplication": "bob"
  }
}
```

Both of these scenarios need to be supported, and the existing API is the string version. What I am trying to do is configure the API so that if the event sent in is a JSON object, it is stringified in the model that arrives in the Action.

Comment: ** I want the value of this property coming from the client to be either a string or a JObject (JSON) ** What do you mean? The HTTP request will always contain your JSON as a string and there is nothing you can do about it. The model binder is the one that could turn that string in a JObject, however I can not help without seeing your binder code.

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53246755/creating-a-modelbinder-for-mongodb-objectid-on-asp-net-core/53303189) might help.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Kirk for a pointer to the solution. I ended up skipping model binding altogether (yay!) and was able to achieve what I needed using a custom serializer with an Attribute on the property: `[JsonConverter(typeof(EventBodyJsonConverter))]`. With this in place I can use `[FromBody]` in the Action to get content aware binding.

```
public class EventBodyJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private JsonSerializer _jsonSerializer;

    public EventBodyJsonConverter()
    {
        _jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(string);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            var eventJObject = _jsonSerializer.Deserialize<JObject>(reader);
            return eventJObject.ToString();
        }

        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
        {
            return reader.Value.ToString();
        }

        throw new Exception();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {

    }
}
```